# Setting Environment variable value through project.json file

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In dotnet RC1 I was able to set my environment variable values in the commands
section of the project.json file.
I use these values for setting my appsettings.ENVIRONMENTNAME.json values in the Startup.cs for targeting different environments

project.json file prior to RC2

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --ASPNET_ENV Development",
    "uat": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --ASPNET_ENV UAT",
    "dev": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --ASPNET_ENV DEV"
  }
```

It was then pretty straight forward to just pass the command name as the iis-command name parameter to dnu publish as below on the build server

```
"C:\Users\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\dnu.cmd" publish --out "C:\PublishedCode\" --iis-command "dev" --no-source --configuration DEV --wwwroot "wwwroot" --wwwroot-out "wwwroot"  --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1
```

With dotnet core 1.0 the official documenation is saying to use [profiles](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html?highlight=aspnetcore_environment) but it doesn't explain how to specify the profiles from the command line, the documentation is still on RC1 version [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html).

How do I set up my configuration so that I can target different environments in my project.json file
and then be able to use these values with the     dotnet cli. 
If needs be I could set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT through
powershell but I'd prefer to do it through a config file like in RC1, i think it's cleaner that way rather than setting environment variables through the build server.

```
 dotnet publish --WHAT DO I DO NOW
```

Answer (score 0):

That kind of information is no longer stored in the project.json. project.json only describes compilation and publishing, not launching the site.

You can add environment variables in the web.config for AspNetCoreModule, but only for one profile: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/hosting/aspnet-core-module.html#child-elements

These variables should be set in the deployment environment rather than being built into the app.